# Different betwee {} and = when C++11 initialize variables

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I used CLion as an IDE, it reports an error in IDE as

> field z must be initialized

It can compile and run. But if I change `const int z{3};` to `const int z=3;`, no error will be reported in IDE. My question is whether it is indeed an error of my codes or it is just a bug in the IDE? Any difference between these two initialization approaches? Did your IDE report this error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    const int x = 3;
    int y;
    const int z{3};
public:
    Test(int);
    int gety(){
        return y;
    }
};

Test::Test(int a){
    y=x+4;
}

int main()
{
    Test test(5);
    std::cout << test.gety() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing this when you compile?  If so, which compiler are you using?

Comment: I didn't see this during compiling. The codes can be compiled and run. It is only reported in IDE. For the IDE, a few ways can fix it, such as remove const, simply using int 'z{3}' or change it to 'const int z=3'. If you copy and past the above codes to your compiler or IDE, can you see the problem? Is this a real error or IDE bug?

Comment: Your code is valid.

Comment: There seems to be a number of reported bugs in JetBrains issue tracker for CLion that relates (or look similar enough) to this (issues with braced init). Most likely a false positive in the static analysis. Annoying maybe, but the code should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

> whether it is indeed an error of my codes

There is no error in the code, it is OK.

> or it is just a bug in the IDE?

It is a bug in whatever generates the error message. The IDE is high on my list of suspects but it could be another tool whose message the IDE relays.

> Any difference between these two initialization approaches?

In this context (default member initializer) both syntaxes are semantically equivalent. There is no difference.